I can't update my url instantly in useQuery's fetchData, how do I do it?

Quando tenho diferença nos parâmetros da url, como page, como
typeProduct, eu mudo a url, como você pode ver no console:
but when do I fetch
the fetch url is outdated, it is only correct on the next rendering.
console.log('fetch url:', url.href);
appears like this in the browser:
newUrl: https://api-storage-products.vercel.app/products?_page=2&_limit=12
fetch url: https://api-storage-products.vercel.app/products?_page=1&_limit=12
that is, it is not performing the fetch with the url I want.
When I do it with normal fetch, it works, but I can't cache it, as the url changes several times, it ends up generating an accumulation of requests that would be resolved with the cache, that's why I use react-query, but I'm having the problem when updating of the url in the fetchData.


Hello, can you please clarify [what you are asking]?
